# Django: Setting up database code tables (aka reference tables, domain tables)?

Tags: django, configuration, django-models, lookup-tables, project-setup

Often times applications will need some database code tables (aka reference tables or domain tables or lookup tables).  Suppose I have a model class called Status with a field called name that could hold values like:

```
Canceled
Pending
InProgress
Complete
```

Where and at what point would I setup these values in Django?  Its like a one time operation to setup these values in the database.  Infrequently, these values could be added to.

And I guess more generically, how do you initialize models with data? For example, say I had a model for holding the make of a car and I want to initialize this list with a set of known values.  How would I do this?

Comment: Could you use [choices](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) for this or it really needs to be in the database so you can add status names through admin?

Comment: For this particular application I'm debating using choices, but for a flexible design I wanted to know how to use db tables. And in general I'd like to know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use [a fixture](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#howto-initial-data) for that.